# Not able to validate xml by converting xml string to stream

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

[image: I am not able to find exact exception, when debugging, I can just find this info]I getting xml through web service in string format and to pass through xmlreader, I am converting the string to a stream object. But cannot figure out what I am missing. The xml and schema mentioned here is a sample.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

            doc.Load("books.xml");
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            XmlTextWriter tx = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
            doc.WriteTo(tx);
            string leadxml = sw.ToString();

            XmlReaderSettings xmlSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            xmlSettings.Schemas = new System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet();
            xmlSettings.Schemas.Add(string.Empty,"books.xsd");
            xmlSettings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(leadxml);
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream, xmlSettings);

            // Parse the file.
            while (reader.Read());


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

        }
    }

}
```

xml is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<bookstore>
  <book genre="autobiography" publicationdate="1981-03-22" ISBN="1-861003-11-0"/>
</bookstore>
```

xsd is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="bookstore">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="book">

        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Any reason not to use XML classes to deal with values directly instead of (incorrectly) converting between strings/streams/byte arrays?

Comment: I guess problem is while converting to stream or xmlreader.create() but not able to figure out.

Comment: -1 to the question: if you don't know what your problem and goal is no one will be able to help you solve it (expected: I want to do XXXX and it fails with YYYY error/unexpected result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if all your doing is getting the Xml into a string, this entire block of code is unnecessary:

```
          XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
          doc.Load("books.xml");
          StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
          XmlTextWriter tx = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
          doc.WriteTo(tx);
          string leadxml = sw.ToString();
```

Instead just do:

```
          string leadxml = File.ReadAllText("books.xml");
```

Secondly, if you have a string already, it is completely unnecessary to do all this conversion on the string. The XmlReader.Create method has a signature which accepts a TextReader. StringReader derives from TextReader. Therefore, this:

```
             byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(leadxml);
             MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
             XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream, xmlSettings);
```

Can be replaced with this:

```
             StringReader leadxmlStringReader = new StringReader(leadXml);
             XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(leadxmlStringReader, xmlSettings);
```

For any further assistance with this question, you will need to provide Exception details and/or specific error messages.

Answer (score 1):

`StringWriter` assumes a UTF-16 encoding by default, which means you'll get an XML declaration with UTF-16 in it. You're then using `Encoding.ASCII` to get a binary representation though, which is incompatible with the UTF-16 declaration.

To be honest, it's not really clear why you're doing this in the first place - there's almost certainly a better way of achieving your goal, but we can't really tell what your goal *is*, so we can't advise what that better way might be.

EDIT: For example, this *might* be what you're really after:

```
XmlReaderSettings xmlSettings = new XmlReaderSettings
{
    Schemas = { { "", "books.xsd" } },
    ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema
}
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("books.xml", xmlSettings))
{
    while (reader.Read()) {}
}
```

Comment: so what should I use instead of UTF-16? UTF-8

Comment: @SidP: You should tell us your real goal, and then we can advise you better. *Why* are you reading from a file, then saving to a string, then converting that string to a byte array?

Comment: I have written above that I am getting the xml through webservice in string format. Here for the sample, I have loaded as a file. So that I don't have to paste the web service code.

Comment: @SidP: So you don't *actually* have any of the `StringWriter` code at all? How much of your code *is* the code in the question? And as Daniel asked, what is the actual problem? Are you getting an exception? If so, what is it? Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: +1 to this/-1 to question... (I suspect that the answer should be XmlDocument.LoadXml)

Comment: I am not able to explain why everyone is blaming. That is the reason why I am asking for help and ur answer is right. The goal is to just validate the xml

Comment: @SidP: "I am not able to explain why everyone is blaming." - because you haven't asked a question. You've presented some code (which isn't representative of your real code, as half of it isn't in your real code) but not said what happens when you try to run it. Did you read the link in my comment?

Comment: Well the actual task is to validate the xm that I get through web service with the xsd what we have.

Comment: @SidP: You *still* haven't said what happens when you run your existing code vs what you want to happen. You haven't asked a question. *Please* read the linked blog post - it'll help you ask much better questions in the future. (Note that if you ask lots of low-quality questions, your account may become banned from asking any more.)